# PHP & MySQL Select From database

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm selecting data from my database, and still its saying I'm in the game. When I'm not, for which I check for.

Any clue how to solve this problem?

```
        $moneda = (CMS == 'uber' ? $users->GetUserVar(USER_ID, moneda) : $myrow[moneda]);
        $isonline = mysql_query("SELECT `online` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ".$_POST['Naam']."");
        $error = array();
        if($isonline == 1)
                $error[] = "De ander moet uit het hotel gaan voordat je belpixels kunt overschrijven.";
```

Comment: Your code is vurnerable to SQL injections. Please fix that problem first. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: `$isonline` is getting the result set from your query - that will only be false if the SQL query fails. You need to get the output of the query with something like mysql_fetch_array first.

Comment: So how is the best way to secure it, I dont get the clue at the "see here" page.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should work on moving away from `mysql_*`, as they are being deprecitated by PHP. http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: Use prepared statements by using PDO or mysqli.

Comment: You really need to read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) before you create a SQL injection that causes severe harm to your application.

Answer (score 1):

```
$isonline = mysql_query("SELECT `online` FROM `users` WHERE `username` =".$_POST['Naam']."");
```

$isonline is not your answer..dude it contains the result object, not the result.

```
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($isonline);
if($row['online']==1){}
```

and use of mysql_query is long deprecated, switch to PDO

and

`$isonline = mysql_query("SELECT online FROM` ..

sql you never put quotations around column names...get rid of the ones around username too.and get one around the username value this one here:

```
$isonline = mysql_query("SELECT online FROM users WHERE username ='".$_POST['Naam']."'");
```

Comment: This ain't working for me let me show you the whole code, maybe you can do something about it:

Comment: `<?php
   $isonline = mysql_query("SELECT `online` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ".$_POST['Naam']."");
   $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($isonline);
   if($row['online']==1)
   {
     $error[] = "De ander moet uit het hotel gaan voordat je belpixels kunt overschrijven.";
   }
            $error = array();
            if($myrow['online'] == 1)
                    $error[] = "Je moet uit het hotel gaan voordat je

    endif;
     
?> `

Comment: get rid of '' around the online

Comment: dude,... no quots around column names... and quotations around values or data,... always always

Comment: and u need a sql book not stackoverflow... get a good mysql book

Comment: Can you escape the `$_POST` variable? This is not a valid answer.

Comment: You **cannot** just go and sling in a user-supplied variable into a query string. You **must** at the very least escape it with `mysql_real_escape_string`. You're right that PDO is better, but your example here has a gigantic SQL injection bug in it as it stands.

Comment: yep, i was pointing out merely the minor mistakes..his query already had so many issues... let the query work first,security follows.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query never returns a single user record; it returns a PHP resource, even if you know the SQL query will only ever return a single record.

In other words: $isonline is not the right name for that variable.  Call it something like $online_query_results, then call

```
$user_record = mysql_fetch_array($online_query_results);
```

This will return the first (and in this case only) result row. Then, instead of testing $isonline, test

```
$user_record['online']
```

Comment: This isn't working either. It should return an error if the user is in the game, which it still doesn't when in the database online is set to 1.

Comment: Can you put a logging statement into this code to see what is actually being returned from your db_query statement or from mysql_fetch_array? for example: 'printr($user_record)'? (Never use printr on a database record result on a live site; the output will include your database username and password). 

If the changes suggested aren't working, the most likely reason is because your database query is returning a nil or empty object.

Comment: Please post the actual query string you're using now. Does it work if you use this query string? --> 

`SELECT online FROM {users} WHERE username = {$_POST['Naam']}`